# How to count occurrences of values of a list in a column of a different dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, jupyter-notebook

I need to count the number of times the values of a list appear in a column of a different DataFrame.

I've tried using `df['Column'].value_counts()`.
However,if a value is in the list but not in the column, it won't show up in the result.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column': [HIGH, HIGH, HIGH, LOW, LOW, LOW, LOW]})

list = ['HIGH', 'MEDIUM', 'LOW']
```

I expect the output to be:

```
HIGH      3
MEDIUM    0
LOW       4
```

But using `.value_counts()` I get:

```
HIGH      3
LOW       4
```

Can someone please point out how I can achieve this? Is it possible to write a piece of code so that my output will always show counts for HIGH, MEDIUM and LOW, regardless of how the data is distributed? (The next time I load the data, it might be possible that there are no HIGH values, instead of MEDIUM)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One quick fix `reindex`

```
df.Column.value_counts().reindex(list,fill_value=0)
HIGH      3
MEDIUM    0
LOW       4
Name: Column, dtype: int64
```

---

Another way `pd.Categorical`

```
pd.Categorical(df.Column,list).value_counts()
HIGH      3
MEDIUM    0
LOW       4
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below, it creates an empty series first and then combines it with value_counts series:

`pd.Series(0, index=list).combine(df.value_counts(), max)`